# statsmodel package grangercausalitytests output explanation?

Tags: time-series, python, statsmodels, granger-causality

Was told to post her from stack overflow.

I'm currently doing a project where I'm trying to find evidence of causality between human activity and global warming. I've been trying to run a granger causality test of annual emissions on global temperature after differencing both variables and checking for unit roots.

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'temp':temperature,'emissions':emissions)
sm.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests(test,15)
```

Can somebody help me make more sense of the output given?

Sample Output for Lag 11 and 14:

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 11
ssr based F test:         F=1.1019  , p=0.3716  , df_denom=76, df_num=11
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=15.7887 , p=0.1492  , df=11
likelihood ratio test: chi2=14.6493 , p=0.1991  , df=11
parameter F test:         F=1.1019  , p=0.3716  , df_denom=76, df_num=11

...
number of lags (no zero) 14
ssr based F test:         F=1.2862  , p=0.2394  , df_denom=67, df_num=14
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=25.8004 , p=0.0274  , df=14
likelihood ratio test: chi2=22.8514 , p=0.0627  , df=14
parameter F test:         F=1.2862  , p=0.2394  , df_denom=67, df_num=14
```

When would the Chi-squared test results be preferable to the F test? I was under the impression that Chi-squared is preferred with higher lag number, but the original sample size is pretty small ( n = 100).

If the null hypothesis of the test is no granger causality, I'm guessing that there under the chi-squared test, emissions 'granger causes' global warming at a 95% CI at lag 14? Please correct me if I'm wrong.